# Rails default value of select tag + active record

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, form-helpers

I'm trying to set the default value of a `select tag` to the value that is `saved in the model in active record`. At the same time, if no value is specified (e.g. on model-creation) I want a `list` to be displayed to select a certain field of the select tag.

This is how I'd like to do it:

```
<% valid_years = Array.new %>
<% for i in 1900..Time.now.year %>
<%   valid_years << i %>
<% end %>
<%= f.label t :label_year_of_birth %>
<%= f.select :year_of_birth, options_for_select(valid_years), class: "" %>
```

However, the value that's saved in active record is `not displayed` in this select tag. Instead, the first value of the array is shown. Also, if I write `options_for_select(valid_years, 1950)`, rails won't put the value to 1950.

However, if I use a simple `text field tag`, rails WILL put the saved value in it.

```
<%= f.label t :label_year_of_birth %>
<%= f.text_field :year_of_birth, class: "" %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
<%= f.select :year_of_birth, options_for_select(valid_years), class: "" %>
```

With

```
<%= f.select :year_of_birth, options_for_select(valid_years, form_for_object_name.year_of_birth), class: "" %>
```

where 
`form_for_object_name` is the object that you are passing to your form since you didn't share the `<%= form_for(?) do |f| %>`.

`options_for_select` takes the second argument i.e. `form_for_object_name.year_of_birth` as the `selected` value.
If `form_for_object_name.year_of_birth` is nil then select will default to the first value of your options i.e. `1900` in your case.

Comment: Thanks! Totally forgot about that. Used it once before :P